# Text after sale price showing FROM and TO dates in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, price

I am using [Customs product price on sale displayed with date limit in Woocommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622856/customs-product-price-on-sale-displayed-with-date-limit-in-woocommerce-3/53624281#53624281) to make a custom formatted price display on products on sale that have a limitation period.

Now I am trying to include also the "from" date. How can I get and include the from date in this code?

Any track is really useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will handle both on sale date from and on sale date to in your price custom display *(require both from and to dates)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // Simple products and variations
        if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'variation' )  )
        {
            $sales_price_from = $product->get_date_on_sale_from();
            $sales_price_to = $product->get_date_on_sale_to();
            if( ! empty($sales_price_from) && ! empty($sales_price_to) ){
                $replacement = ' </ins> <span class="notice-price">(on offer from ' . date( 'j.M.Y', $sales_price_from->getTimestamp() ) . ' until ';
                return str_replace( '</ins>', $replacement . date( 'j.M.Y', $sales_price_to->getTimestamp() ) . ')</span>', $price );
            }
        }
        // Variable products
        else if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) )
        {
            $from = $to = '';
            // Loop through variations
            foreach ( $product->get_children() as $key => $variation_id ) {
                $variation        = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                $sales_price_from = $variation->get_date_on_sale_from();
                $sales_price_to   = $variation->get_date_on_sale_to();

                if( ! empty($sales_price_from) && ! empty($sales_price_to) ){
                    $date_from = date( 'j.M.Y', $sales_price_from->getTimestamp() );
                    $date_to   = date( 'j.M.Y', $sales_price_to->getTimestamp() );
                    $class     = $key == 0 ? 'class="active"' : '';
                    $from     .= '<i data-id="'.$variation_id.'" data-order="'.($key + 1).'" '.$class.'>'. $date_from .'</i>';
                    $to       .= '<i data-id="'.$variation_id.'" data-order="'.($key + 1).'" '.$class.'>'. $date_to .'</i>';
                }
            }
            if( ! empty($content) ){
                return $price . ' <span class="notice-price">(on offer from ' . $from . ' until ' . $to .')</span>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Welcome… Now for variable products, you might rethink the display, because if there is many variation on sale with dates, it will be strange.

Comment: This code is not working, how to fix it? don't display at all. The other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622856/customs-product-price-on-sale-displayed-with-date-limit-in-woocommerce-3 yes (but showing all dates in a row).

Comment: @FilipeOS Sorry I just tested the code again and it works… So may be you should ask a question, including the related answer thread link, explaining what is not working adding all necessary details…

Comment: Done, thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902675/displaying-sale-from-and-to-woocommerce @LoicTheAztec